# laptop screen is static when woken up

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, sleep, reboot

My laptop screen does this whenever it wakes up and the only way to fix it seems to be force rebooting it. Any ideas on what will fix it? I'm currently updating my graphics drivers to see if that fixes it. My laptop is an inspiron 15 7000 7559. It's gpu is an nvidia geforce gtx 1050 Ti. It also has intel HD graphics 630, but I never use the intel hd graphics because the nvidia is more powerful.

This is what happens when I wake up my computer:

[image: This is what happens when I wake up my computer.]

Comment: I've got something similar on one of my laptops when returning from hibernate/shut-down, except that I get a blank screen. Like you, I have gone through driver updates, etc, without success, but I have found that returning from sleep restores the display, and I do this by making lid closing invoke sleep (as opposed to hibernate), so I can sleep without using the keyboard or mouse.

Comment: There is zero information here we have to go on. At least specify the make and model of your laptop. Additionally specify anything you have done to try to resolve the issue. A photo of the issue could help. We can’t answer your question if we have absolutely nothing to go on.

Comment: My laptop appears to have fixed itself.

Comment: It started happening again. My laptop is an inspiron 15 7000 7559. I'm not sure why the picture I added isn't appearing on the original post.

Comment: Added the picture

Comment: Please [update your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1264273/edit) with detailed information about that laptop of yours. // Either way, it looks like the GPU or its driver are defective.

Comment: I updated my gpu driver and it didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

try rolling back your intel graphics driver: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000008628/graphics-drivers.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.